# is there any possible on using dynamic rendering image inside the SVG tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, quasar-framework

i am facing a problem regarding the SVG and :src binding. Without the SVG tag my dynamic rendering for img work perfectly but once implemented the SVG tag the :src is not functioning and image is not showing. But i need the SVG tag to do the polygons as each time user hover on the picture the part of the picture will be highlighted. Seem like src can only work when static data is passed in

```
<template>
  <div>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="computed_viewBox" >
        <!-- here need to change -->
        <!-- <img
          svg-inline
          src="./Carline - Sedan 4 Doors.svg"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
        /> -->
        <!-- <VueSimpleSVG
          custom-id="svgId"
          :src="showImage"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          @load="svgLoaded()"
        /> -->
        <!-- <img svg-inline :src="showImageRequire" width="100%" height="100%" /> -->
         <img v-svg-inline :src="showImage" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
        <!-- <path :d="bodyTypeImagePath"/> -->
        <!-- <img v-bind:src="'~svg/car_line_diagram/'+showImage+'.svg'" width="100%" height="100%" /> -->
        
      </svg>
    <br />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
showImage() {
      if (!this.bodyTypeImagePath) {
        return;
      }
      var fileName = this.bodyTypeImagePath;

      console.log("fileName")
      console.log(fileName)
      // var path =`~svg/car_line_diagram/${fileName}.svg`
      var path =`./${fileName}.svg`

      // return fileName;
      // return require(`../../assets/car_line_diagram/${fileName}.svg`);
      return path 
    },
```

Comment: img is a html tag and won't work in SVG. The SVG equivalent is the [image tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image).

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the hint buddy! I have solved the problem by replacing the <img> with <image> . My picture load successfully after changing to code below

<image :href="showImage" width="100%" height="100%" />